# Is there any way to backtrack to previous areas?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Since I'm out hunting for all the achievements, including Sightseer, and all the Voxophone records, I'd like to go back to past areas to finish up the rest of the achievements.

Can you backtrack to previous areas? Or is it once you leave you can't go back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the purpose of Achievements, you can backtrack by loading previous chapters via the menu. Play Game > Load Chapter. This only works for the 'Eavesdropper' and 'Sightseer' Achievements however. The last collectible achievement 'Infused With Greatness' must be completed on a single playthrough so if you can remember the first Infusion that you missed you can load that chapter and play to the end, getting all of the Infusions and it will pop.

Answer (score 4):

It depends from area to area. I think at some points you can backtrack. However, if your question is meaning to ask if you can backtrack indefinitely, I don't think that that is possible.

Make sure to search every area very well.